# How can a compute the Thai customs taxes before receiving a package from outside Thailand?

Tags: international, customs, thailand

I plan to receive a package sent from France to Bangkok, Thailand. The package contains 200 USD worth of shampoo and hair conditioner. How can a compute the Thai customs taxes before receiving a package?

---

What I have found so far:

I read on https://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/special-reports/355336/online-shopping-can-be-quite-taxing ([mirror](https://archive.vn/FaRr4)):

> That daunting litany of taxes and duties, which might represent nearly 100% of the base purchase price, would be enough to stop most internet shoppers in their tracks. **The Customs Tariff Schedule specifies which duties and taxes are applicable to particular goods.** Today, we will examine the process of importing personal consumer items bought over the internet through one of the world's most popular internet-based businesses: Amazon.

I believe that the Customs Tariff Schedule is [this document](https://tax.dtn.go.th/agreement/download/85) ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/2020-tariff-customs-schedule-of-thailand)).

[image]

I have two issues with this document:

1. It is not up-to-date: we are 2020, and it only specifies up to 2010
2. In 2009, does this means that my shampoo is taxed at 20 % + 5 % = 25%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found http://itd.customs.go.th/igtf/en/main_frame.jsp to compute the customs taxes, which seems more up-to-date:

[image]

[image]

If you're unhappy with the custom taxes your package received (they tend to be quite random), call the following number:

[image]